# Fbprophet installation error - failed building wheel for fbprophet

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, facebook-prophet

I am trying to install fbprophet for Python using Pip install, but failing. I have already installed Pystan.

Can I import it using Anaconda Navigator?

Can someone please help.

**Failed building wheel for fbprophet**

```
Running setup.py clean for fbprophet
Failed to build fbprophet
Installing collected packages: fbprophet
  Running setup.py install for fbprophet ... error
    Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SJ-Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bsm4sxla\\fbprophet\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\SJ-Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-kvck8fw1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\fbprophet
    creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_models
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\SJ-Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bsm4sxla\fbprophet\setup.py", line 126, in <module>
        """
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\SJ-Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bsm4sxla\fbprophet\setup.py", line 46, in run
        build_stan_models(target_dir)
      File "C:\Users\SJ-Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bsm4sxla\fbprophet\setup.py", line 28, in build_stan_models
        from pystan import StanModel
    ImportError: cannot import name 'StanModel'
```

Comment: I also tried installing fbprophet using conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet. But it didnt work either.

Answer (score 20):

Fundamental step:
Switch to your environment in your Anaconda prompt: 
`conda activate name-of-your-python-enviornment`

Then the following steps shall work:

1. On Prompt install Ephem:

   ```
   conda install -c anaconda ephem
   ```
2. Install Pystan:

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge pystan
   ```
3. Finally install Fbprophet:

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
   ```
4. If exists error from holidays package

   ```
   pip install holidays==0.9.12
   ```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/892

Reference for Holiday package error: https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1300

Comment: I got this to work after lowering my environment's Python version below 3.9

Comment: This worked for me. I did not have to do the fundamental step nor step 4. Thanks!

Comment: After a full day of wasting my time, thanks for this. Finally able to work.

Answer (score 8):

The `fbprophet` package has been renamed to `prophet`. Using below command in Anaconda prompt worked for me:

```
pip install prophet
```

then you can import using below command:

```
from prophet import Prophet
```

Comment: Saved my day! was struggling with fbprophet and was throwing up wierd CPP errors.

Answer (score 6):

Use offline package installer: this works with Python 3.8. and Python 3.9.x

```
pip install localpip 
localpip install fbprophet
```

Answer (score 3):

I could install fbprophet using conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet.
This was failing too due to permission issue
My folder had 'read-only' permissions. I modified it to read-write. Then reran the command and was able to install fbprophet

Answer (score 2):

So after I did

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

I got at the end:

```
EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

ProgramData is system folder, so changed r-w permissions(took few minutes), and I also did this for C:\Program Files\Python37 path with Lib folder.

Comment: There is a solutions in another branch - As a solution, I re-installed Anaconda just for me and now the base environment is in \AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I'm not sure but it looks as though your answer ends with a question? If you're not asking a question (as recognised by SO), please can you make the last sentence a bit clearer _ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the following environment

OSX: Big Sur 11.6

python: python:3.7-slim

```
$ pip install pystan==2.19
$ pip install fbprophet
```

Answer (score 1):

For this stack:

- CentOS: 7
- Python: 3.8
- GCC: 4.8.5
- PyStan: 2.19.1.1
- FbProphet: 0.7.1

You need these packages:

- centos-release-scl devtoolset-8

Enable SCL devtoolset-8

```
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable
```

- rh-python38-python rh-python38-python-devel
- pip install pystan==2.19.1.1

Docker image with HTTPD MOD_WSGI and FBPROPHET...

```
FROM centos:7

EXPOSE 80

# Install Apache
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install centos-release-scl
RUN yum -y install httpd httpd-tools rh-python38-python-mod_wsgi.x86_64 devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc-c++ rh-python38-python rh-python38-python-devel

# Copy the wsgi module to Apache HTTP Server modules folder
RUN cp /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_rh-python38-wsgi.so /lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so

ENV PATH="/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /
COPY ROOT .

WORKDIR /opt/rh/rh-python38/root
RUN ./usr/bin/python3 /etc/get-pip.py

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-fb.sh && /usr/local/bin/install-fb.sh
RUN pip install -r /etc/requirements.txt

# Start Apache
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

The script install-fb.sh contains this code:

```
$ cat ROOT/usr/local/bin/install-fb.sh
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/enable
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1 fbprophet==0.7.1
```

The reason to put it in its own script is the SCL enable line, to avoid the gcc not found error.

I hope this helps, getting all these software packages running together is not a piece of cake :)

Answer (score 0):

Docker Image: python 3.8-slim

This worked for me:

```
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
pip install fbprophet
```

Comment: Please mention your working environment or Operating System, so it would help others who view your answer.

Answer (score 0):

macOS Big Sur  11.5.2

python 3.7

This worked for me:

```
pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
sudo pip install fbprophet==0.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

[FB prophet documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/installation.html#python) recommends using conda for windows users as the easiest way for installing prophet.
In my case, the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61353951/no-module-named-fbprophet) solved the problem (win10):

```
conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet -y
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a virtual environment using:

`conda create --name myenv`

2. Activate the environment using:

`conda activate myenv`

3. Install `ephem` using:

`conda install -c anaconda ephem`

4. Install `pystan` using

`conda install -c conda-forge pystan`

5. Install the `fbrprophet` using

`conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet`

6. At the end install `holidays`:

`pip install holidays==0.9.12`

7. If it still doesn't work try this at last:

`conda install psycopg2`

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of research, I found the solution for installing fbprophet on windows 10.

Step 1: Check the kernel in jupyter.
Locate the folder \jupyter\kernels\python3 and check the python exe location used by the kernel.
Mine was pointing to - Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
open CMD prompt and go to above dir.

I am skipping pystan installation as I already installed pystan using pip command.

Step 2 : Download the file "Twisted-20.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

python -m pip install /Twisted-20.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Step 3 : pip install fbprophet

Installing collected packages: fbprophet
Successfully installed fbprophet-0.6

Step 4 : python

import fbprophet

fbprophet.**version**

'0.6'

Comment: What is Twisted? Why is it necessary here?

Answer (score -1):

fbprophet has been renamed by prophet hence 1st install
**pip install pystan==2.19.1.1**
then do
**python -m pip install prophet**
this will work!
then to import do
**from prophet import Prophet**

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me:

```
pip install prophet
pip install fbprophet
```

Comment: 'prophet' and 'fbprophet' are the same library except different versions.  fbprophet was renamed with the introduction of Prophet and it is the latest and greatest. you dont need both as they each have their own dependencies for supporting libraries such as pystan

Comment: Yes but somehow using both commands at same time worked for me.