# Why does Anaconda Prompt say that Python=3.9 when I've downloaded Python version 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm trying to install facebook prophet using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889404/fbprophet-installation-error-failed-building-wheel-for-fbprophet) but I get an error saying that fbprophet requires python versions lower than 3.8 and that I have 3.9. However I downloaded and installed 3.7.

Here is the error message I get in Anaconda Prompt:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.|
                                                                                                                       /failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - fbprophet -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9
```

And when I run `python -V`, low and behold I get indeed that my version is Python 3.9.7. However, checking my programs I see this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: You have probably updated your conda environment and Windows might not be updating correctly. I would suggest creating a virtual environment for your project, makes managing packages and differentiating between different packages easier. You can also manage the python version with conda environment: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I followed the link and completed to step 3. Then I activated that enviornment and after checking version, I still get 3.9.7. Do I need to complete step 4 too? Seems a bit tedious if I need to do it with every package.

Comment: You need to activate your environment once you have created it, there is a section there about it too. Just make sure you are using command prompt on Windows, since PowerShell doesn't play nice with conda, at least in my experience. For packages, you have to specify every package, but conda takes package dependencies unless you tell it not to. Keep in mind you can specify multiple packages in a single go like `conda install -n myenv scipy pandas ...`.