# Error when pip install fbprophet - ERROR: Failed building wheel for fbprophet

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, virtualenv, facebook-prophet

### Problem

I am trying to install the python package fbprophet and plotly by typing `pip install fbprophet` and `pip install plotly`, but when attempt to do so, I receive the following error:

```
> Building wheels for collected packages: fbprophet
> Building wheel for fbprophet (setup.py) ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> 
> python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
> exit code: 1
> [122 lines of output]
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build\lib
> creating build\lib\fbprophet
> creating build\lib\fbprophet\stan_model
> Importing plotly failed. Interactive plots will not work.
> COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL anon_model_f5236004a3fd5b8429270d00efcc0cf9 NOW.
> MSVC compiler is not supported
> 
> 
> ...
> 
> [end of output]
> 
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: legacy-install-failure
> 
> Encountered error while trying to install package.
> fbprophet
> 
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for output from the failure.
>
```

(Full error can be found in this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Mi5c7k4Y)

### What I've tried

I tried to run `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. I also tried to reinstall MSVC 2022 through Microsoft Visual Studio Builds tools.[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Visual Studio Builds tools]

### Update

I have now found a post discussing a very similiar issue ([here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889404/fbprophet-installation-error-failed-building-wheel-for-fbprophet)) but through anaconda, and I am not sure how to solve my issue. Now I am not using anaconda, and I have no experience with virtual environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fbprophet` is now called `prophet`, just install using wheels.

https://pypi.org/project/prophet/#files